# How to make this regular expression case insensitive without RegexOptions.IgnoreCase?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to match two words for gender but I want to accept all cases
For example: male, Male, MalE

I'm using it as an attribute so it can be used for both client and server validations...

```
[RegularExpression(RegExKeys.Gender, ErrorMessage = ConstantKeys.ValidationMessage_Gender_RegEx)]
```

This is my regular expression:

```
public const string Gender = @"^\b(male|female)\b$";
```

I was trying to add (?i) in different places but I get jquery errors with that on... or maybe I didn't do it correctly...

Any idea how to make this RegEx work for both client and server?

Comment: You can try `^(?:[fF][Ee])?[mM][aA][Ll][Ee]$`. The problem with `(?i)` arises due to JS lack of inline modifier support. Note that `\b` is totally redundant here. In other words, `\b` between `^` and `f`/`m` always matches.

Comment: Maybe this is just a simplified example. Otherwise converting to upper (or lower) case and just checking for the two alternatives (with no regex at all) seems to be much simpler / more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ain't pretty but if that's what you need :

```
^\b([mM][aA][lL][eE]|[fF][eE][mM][aA][lL][eE])\b$
```

**Update 1**

The word boundaries are not needed as noted in the comments

```
^([mM][aA][lL][eE]|[fF][eE][mM][aA][lL][eE])$
```

Comment: `^\b([fF][eE])?[mM][aA][lL][eE]\b$` is a bit shorter and probably easier to read

Comment: The word boundaries are redundant since the pattern is already anchored.

Comment: I also think it's not needed. I'll update the answer

Comment: This is really horrible... but it works... I was hoping to learn how to match whole words while each word is case insensitive...

Comment: @Yovav In order to "match whole words while each word is case insensitive" you would have to enumerate all possibilities `[male|Male|mAle|...`, you see where that's going.  At that point, what's the point in using a regular expression?  I mean you could move just the `[fe]|[Fe]|[FE]|[fE]` portion to the front of the "male" part of the pattern and then it's actually a regular expression and not just different syntax for if/else or switch type logic.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `toLowerCase()` on the string on the client (`JavaScript` syntax), and `ToLower()` on the string on the server (`C#` syntax), before evaluating the string for matches?

Comment: Because I need it for client validation - it shows the validation messages while the user is typing... so I want to accept all variations while it is being typed...

Comment: This seems like a more elegant solution than the accepted answer, although it doesn't actually make the regex case insensitive.  @Yovav what is the actual reason you can't use `testStr.toLowerCase()` on the client and `testStr.ToLower()` on the server before feeding it into your regex?